# How to crop polygon to be within a rectangular region

Tags: python, computer-vision, geometry, polygon, shapely

So I have a `numpy` polygon array of shape `(N, 2)` that I want to crop such that it is within the bounds of the `256x256` image seen in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlOfQ.png). That is, I want to crop this polygon such that it matches with the boundaries of the yellow mask inside the `256x256` region; the output polygon should have an area equivalent to this mask and have a shape `(Mx2)`.

As seen in the image, I already rasterized the polygon to create the binary mask such that it is within the bounds `256x256`. However, I also want to crop the polygon such that it matches with the boundary of the binary mask. How can I do this? I was thinking of doing it with `shapely` by creating a rectangular polygon `[(0,0), (0,256), (256,256), (256,0)]`, however, I realized there might be a lot of edge cases that I have to handle:

- The box intersects with the polygon, thus, we want to get the intersecting polygon
- The box is completely inside the polygon, thus, output the box
- The polygon is completely inside the box, thus, output the original polygon
- Intersection results in multiple polygons, need to handle this

Maybe it isn't so bad to code something to handle all this, but is there some sort of library that can do this quickly and easily?

Comment: You should add a description of your edge cases to your question, because the most obvious solution is to use shapely as you suggest. In order to suggest alternates, we all have to understand why you think shapely won't work for your case.

Comment: Updated! But yeah maybe shapely is the easiest way I suppose... Just wanted to check if there is anything off the shelf before I try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shapely will work just fine for your problem. Your edge cases are standard cases for intersection of two generic polygons and you can use `Polygon.intersection` ([link](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.intersection)). If the intersection results in multiple polygons then `Polygon.intersection` will just give you a `MultiPolygon`. Here's an example to illustrate:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.affinity import scale,translate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# build squiggly polygon
theta=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
x=np.cos(theta)+0.1*np.sin(theta*10)
y=np.sin(theta)
A=Polygon(np.column_stack((x,y)))

# build a box
B=Polygon([[-.25,-1.5],[.25,-1.5],[.25,1.25],[-.25,1.25],[-.25,-1.5]])
# Intersection
C=A.intersection(B)
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.plot(A.boundary.xy[0],A.boundary.xy[1],'k',label='A')
plt.plot(B.boundary.xy[0],B.boundary.xy[1],'b',label='B')
plt.plot(C.boundary.xy[0],C.boundary.xy[1],'--r',label='C')
plt.title('standard intersection')

# box in squiggly
B1=scale(B,0.5,0.5)
C=A.intersection(B1)
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.plot(A.boundary.xy[0],A.boundary.xy[1],'k',label='A')
plt.plot(B1.boundary.xy[0],B1.boundary.xy[1],'b',label='B')
plt.plot(C.boundary.xy[0],C.boundary.xy[1],'--r',label='C')
plt.title('box in squiggly')

# squiggly in box
B1=scale(B,5,5)
C=A.intersection(B1)
plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.plot(A.boundary.xy[0],A.boundary.xy[1],'k',label='A')
plt.plot(B1.boundary.xy[0],B1.boundary.xy[1],'b',label='B')
plt.plot(C.boundary.xy[0],C.boundary.xy[1],'--r',label='C')
plt.title('squiggly in box')

# multipolygons
B1=translate(B,1.2,0)
C=A.intersection(B1)
plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.plot(A.boundary.xy[0],A.boundary.xy[1],'k',label='A')
plt.plot(B1.boundary.xy[0],B1.boundary.xy[1],'b',label='B')

for poly in C:
    plt.plot(poly.boundary.xy[0],poly.boundary.xy[1],'--r',label='C')

plt.title('multipolygons')
plt.show()
```

which produces the following figure

[image: using shapely to find intersection of two polygons]

Comment: Thanks! Just wondering, how is `.boundary` different from `.exterior`?